# Can credit score be sponsored?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I vaguely know that a good credit score is very important in the US (we do not have such concept in France for individuals).

I was wondering whether such credit score can be boosted through some kind of sponsorship?

A real life scenario would be a company absolutely willing to bring in a very senior employee from abroad who would certainly want to avoid being treated as a fresh graduate, credit-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the possibility of being made an "authorized user" of someone else's credit account and getting some credit history benefit -- see [here](https://twocents.lifehacker.com/what-happens-if-i-add-an-authorized-user-on-my-credit-c-1678163631) and [here](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/finance/authorized-user-credit-score/).

In addition, a [*corporate* credit card](https://www.valuepenguin.com/corporate-credit-cards-explanation-comparison) *may* not require as much regarding an employee's personal credit history, so the company could more readily set them up with a "mainstream" card and reasonable credit limit at least for company business.

Answer (score 1):

No. However, there is a concept of co-signing loans.

For example, many first-time home-buyers are unable to qualify for a mortgage, but often a parent is willing to co-sign. That means the bank thinks the home-buyer is not a good credit risk, but the co-signee, the parent, is willing to put their own wealth on the line. In this case, if the home-buyer fails to make the mortgage payments, the parent will have to cover the difference and may see their credit rating substantially impacted.

Co-signing a loan is almost always a terrible idea. Quite literally, the bank is saying the person is not sufficiently credit-worthy to take on the loan.

In your example, the company may be willing to co-sign loans, even though it's almost certainly a terrible idea for them. Alternatively, some companies are willing to offer a loan directly to the employee. This is rare but not unheard of, particularly for very large companies.

Comment: Doesn't seem like necessarily a "terrible idea" for the company in this case, since they know something about the person's reliability and job stability that lenders aren't taking into account, plus they have a big stick because the person's career will presumably be made to suffer if they fall behind on a company-sponsored loan.

Comment: It is a common procedure in at least one large company. If they want an employee to come as a delegate to the US, they _have to_ - he couldn't even rent a flat without it. Most US residents don't understand that _no_ credit score is much worse than a bad credit score - you are _helpless_, and nobody wants to do business with you. No car, no flat, no insurance, no checking account (you can't even get paid), etc.

Comment: @nanoman , they simply deduct the payments from your salary. Not much risk.

Comment: We also have this concepg of co-signing, usually for a loan or a rent. I do not think z company would be co signing everything, though (it becomes weird after some time). I thought that credit score was meant to be a measure of trusy, and therefore a large company coulf somrhow vouch for someone's trustiness. But thid is not the case from your answer, thanks.

Comment: @Aganju I think people routinely get basic checking accounts before they have a credit history. Regarding deducting loan payments from salary, I'm surprised that would happen for loans *co-signed* (rather than made directly) by the company, but perhaps. In any case, sounds like you agree with my critique of that part of the answer.